# PHP RegEx extension - How to strip only url=*?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I've written a regular expression to strip out BBCode tags - it just strips the allowed tags out (for later counting the string length without the tags).

I'm not an expert when it comes to regular expressions - so after an hour I found this pretty much working:

```
$pattern = "/\[\/?(i|b|u|url(.*?)|list|li)[\]\[]*\]/i";
$stripped = preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
```

It only strips the allowed six tags (and no more - which it is supposed to) and the special tag 'url' which can be extended like 'url=http://someurl'.

I.e.

```
in:  [url=someurl]Lorem[/url] ipsum [test]dolor[/test] sit [b]amet[/b].
out: Lorem ipsum [test]dolor[/test] sit amet.
```

But the problem is, that it doesn't just strip out 'url=[sometext]' but also 'urlipsum'.
I tried to add an '=' for parsing but couldn't get to the point.

Does anyone has a hint for me how to only strip out url when it comes with the =?

Comment: BBCode is a language which is too complex to be parsabale by regex. Have you tried a BBCode parser?

Comment: I have a component for the output but none that just strips all tags. I just use it for counting the length - because the bbcode tags don't count as used characters when inserting tags.

The Pear class I found for BBcode couldn't live up to my expectations and did more than I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$pattern = '/\[\/?(i|b|u|url(=[^\]]+)?|list|li)[\]\[]*\]/i';
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!

I added protocols for extra tests - since I don't want other than http(s), ftp and mailto:

     "/\[\/?(i|b|u|url(=(http|https|ftp|mailto)[^\]]+)?|list|li)[\]\[]*\]/i"

Answer (score 0):

```
  $pattern = "/\[\/?(i|b|u|url=(.*?)|url(?=\])|list|li)[\]\[]*\]/i";
```

Comment: This also strips the url-tag when written without an equal sign - I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the "greediness" of the quantifiers, try adding "U" pattern modifier or remove the question mark in ".*?", see [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).